# Sessions - Two browser windows to use separate sessions

Tags: c#, session

My website consists of a main dashboard page with a list of buildings.

By clicking on one building it opens a new browser window with many functions and features on that specific building.

With that being the case, I can have multiple browser windows open at one shot each representing another building's data. How can I set up that session data doesn't get mixed up between windows?

Comment: There may be a security concern if this were possible. AFAIK it is not possible in modern browsers because fully new sessions (ie: new processes) started on the hosting machine would be too easy an attack and, at the same time, something the source browser instance (the first process) would not be able to control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify each building's information by appending the building's unique identifier as part of the key when you store the data in session.

So instead of doing:

```
Session["Building"] = something;
```

do

```
Session["Building_"+buildingID] = something;
```

Now, using the building id, you can always find the appropriate info belonging to the building in the current window.

With that said, I would question why do you actually need to store this in Session? Isn't it cheap to get the data from the database every time? I wouldn't worry about performance unless you have *really* expensive operations on the database side.

Comment: It's not just the buildingID that I'm storing in session. I'm modifying an existing website with hundreds of sessions being used for the functionality of the website and I am adding the ability to view more than one building at a time.

Comment: @Diane2 is there a good reason to store things in session? Is performance an issue? Is the database call prohibitively expensive? If not, and since you are rewriting it, take this opportunity to get rid of that convoluted logic. It will make your life easier.

Comment: I use sessions for setting values in one spot that I need to access in another function or postback. Could you think of a way to get around it.

Comment: @Diane2 yes, you can pass parameters in the URL, for example. You can also look into Routing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd329551(v=vs.100).aspx) as an option to build urls that encapsulate different parameters, etc. Your question is too broad to give you a concrete implementation but hopefully these are helpful pointers.

Answer (score 0):

We're using a combination of storing an ID in ViewState on a given page to test against the ID of a complex Session object which handles different windows' data. Given the differences in tab, page and session handling by the different browsers, you can get some really quirky behavior.

Comment: Fio, what do you suggest?

Comment: It sounds like your application is "line of business". So you can define the browser that you will support and code to its behavior. Supporting multiple browsers for tab/window/session gets really messy and there is no easy solution.